# How to add icon in button using library(tcltk) in R?

Tags: r, user-interface

I use the library (tcltk) in R to make the GUI. Code to create a button is :

```
tt <- tktoplevel()
button.widget <- tkbutton(tt, text = "", command = function())
```

I want the existing button on the GUI has an icon. How is the code to add the icon in the button using the library (tcltk) in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `tkimage.create` function to create a Tcl-level representation of an image file. Note that there are some limitations on image formats and I believe GIF is the easiest to work with. Then, you specify the image as the `image` argument to `tkbutton`. Here's an example using, [an `Example.gif` from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8f/Example.gif):

```
library("tcltk")
img <- tclVar()
tclimg <- tkimage.create("photo", img, file = "Example.gif")
tt <- tktoplevel()
button.widget <- tkbutton(tt, text = "Click me!", image = tclimg, compound = "top",
                          command = function() tkmessageBox(message = "Hello!"))
tkgrid(button.widget)
```

[image]

You can control the relative placement of the image and text on the button using the `compound` argument:

- "none" (display only the image if present, otherwise the text; the default)
- "text" (text only)
- "image" (image only)
- "center" (text in center of image)
- "top" (image above text)
- "left" (image left of text)
- "bottom" (image below text)
- "right" (image right of text)

Comment: I have run the code that you provided. The result was that it only displays the image icon but do not display the text. How can I make an image icon and text appears in a button?